# Unable to upload an image on flutter ,Build failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image: SS of debug console]

I am unable to use images and built is getting failed

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Folder directly into some drive better other than C:/ if available  . It appears to be permission issue.